# Problem in matching 2 data frames from different dataframe , how to let R return the original value instead of having the NA values

Tags: r, dplyr

The original dataframe was just location of different username.
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EytM.png)

Then I perform delimiter splitting by "," for the location. And that is how I have gotten 6 columns of location. I am trying to figure out the country of each user, that is why I am trying to do mapping towards the world cities data, where it has the cities and countries in it.

```
library(maps)
world=world.cities
colnames(world)=c("city","country","pop","lat","long","capital")
```

I am trying to match the location_1, location_2,...location_6 columns in the first data frame to check if there is a match with the country column in the second data frame.
I have this code with me and it works and I have gotten the some countries filled in df1.

```
df1$country<- df2$country[ match(df1$location_1, df2$country)]
```

However, when I am trying to run the same code again for the rest of the locations. It didn't work, it just pop out NA values, I am thinking if there is a way that whenever there is a column with NA value, it just skip that particular matching with df2.
[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wW39.png) 
[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPHgM.png)

```
df1$country<- df2$country[ match(df1$location_1, df2$country)]
df1$country<- df2$country[ match(df1$location_2, df2$country)]
df1$country<- df2$country[ match(df1$location_3, df2$country)]
df1$country<- df2$country[ match(df1$location_4, df2$country)]
df1$country<- df2$country[ match(df1$location_1, df2$country)]
```

I am able to code them manually by removing the country that have been matched and leave the NA columns to be matched but it is too costly for time. See the code below:

```
 df1$country<- df2$country[ match(df1$location_1, df2$country)]
df3=df1 %>% filter(is.na(country))
df3$country<- df2$country[ match(df3$location_2, df2$country)]
 df4=df3 %>% filter(is.na(country))
```

I have done something like that and it works but it is really not what I want. I am thinking if there is any other way.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Without data.frame in code, and not in screenshot, it's difficult to test.

If the locations on the same row are not from same country, what are we doing ?

My answer could be:

```
df1 <- (
  df1 
  %>% dplyr::left_join (df2, by=c("location_1"="country"), suffix = c(".x", ".y") )
  %>% dplyr::left_join (df2, by=c("location_2"="country"), suffix = c(".x", ".z")  )# etc
  %>% mutate (
             country= ifelse(is.na(city.y),location_1.x,country.y),
             country= ifelse(is.na(city.y),location_1.x,country.z),
  ) 
)
```

But I don't understand all your datas.

Comment: I have updated the dataframe to get you the rough idea about it. My code for  
    df1$country<- df2$country[ match(df1$location_1, df2$country)] actually works. However, I have to subset every single time before I match again for another column.   *(Please check the last part of my post.)

Comment: Also, there is no NA column for the second df, as it is from a library in which I am planning to match my first data frame to